# Flask.jsonify: JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR is False but the output is still pretty

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jsonify

I have:

```
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = False
```

and the docs. say that even by default is False.

However, my output is still pretty:

```
{
  "p": {
    "e": {
      "n": {
        "c": "something..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this with `FLASK_ENV=development`? I find this still pretty prints, regardless of the `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` setting.  However if you execute with just `flask run` (production mode) pretty printing is off, unless that variables is set to `True`.

Comment: @v25 I am using `Gunicorn + Nginx`. I haven't set anything explicitly to `development` mode except for `app.debug = True`.

Comment: The documentation states that if app.debug = True, it will still pretty print. Try by changing it to app.debug = False.